# R - Export Extracted Text Data (Each Instance as Row) to data.frame Format

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, text-extraction

I'm trying to extract/export text from i number of standardized instances within i number of standardized .txt forms into a data frame where each instance is a separate row. I then want to export that data as an .xlsx file. So far, I can successfully extract the data (though the algorithm extracts a little more than the stated gregexpr() parameters) but can only export as .txt as a lump sum of text.

1. How can I create a data frame of the extracted txt-files' text where each instance has its own row?
   (Once the data is in a data.frame format, I know how to export as xlsx from there.)
2. How can I extract only the data from the parameters I have set?

With help (particularly from [Ben from the comments of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445659/use-r-to-convert-pdf-files-to-text-files-for-text-mining?rq=1)), here is what I have so far:

```
# Txt Data Format
txt 1 <-
"A. The First:  abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
 B. The Second: abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
 C. The Third:  abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
 D. The Fourth: abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.

 A. The First:  abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
 B. The Second: abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
 C. The Third:  abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
 D. The Fourth: abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz."

txt 2 <-
"A. The First:  abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
 B. The Second: abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
 C. The Third:  abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
 D. The Fourth: abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.

 A. The First:  abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
 B. The Second: abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
 C. The Third:  abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
 D. The Fourth: abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz."


#################################
# Directory and Text Extraction #
#################################

dest <- "C:/Desktop/"
docs_text <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "txt",  full.names = TRUE)

## Assumes that all the content I want to extract is between "A." and "C." in 
## the text while ignoring "C." and "D." content.

docs_list <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "txt",  full.names = TRUE)
docs_doc <- lapply(docs_list, function(i) {
  j <- paste0(scan(i, what = character()), collapse = " ")
  regmatches(j, gregexpr("(?<=A. The First).*?(?=C. The Third)", j, perl=TRUE))
})

lapply(1:length(docs_doc),  function(i) write.table(docs_doc[i], file=paste(docs_list[i], " ", 
" ", sep="."), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, eol = " " ))
```

Current output looks like this where all of the text is in one line and captures more than just between "A." and "C.":

[image: Current Output]

Desired output would look like this where multiple lines of text only between "A." and "C." is captured and where each multi-line capture is assigned one line each instance:

[image: Desired Output]

Any help you could provide would be tremendously helpful!

I'm ultimately trying to develop an NLP model that can extract standardized form data from hundreds of large PDFs for a year over year repository. If this post suggests I'm not thinking about how to approach this problem efficiently/effectively, I'm open to direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `dplyr` for the convenience of the `tibble` object and the very effective `bind_rows` command:

```
dest <- "~"
docs_text <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "txt",  full.names = TRUE)

library(dplyr)

docs_df <- lapply(docs_text, function(f) {
  lines <- readLines(f)
  tibble(
    file = basename(f),
    line = seq_along(lines),
    text = lines
  )
  }) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Once you have a proper `data.frame` it's easy to subset it using `filter` and `grepl` to look for matching text. I'm using the regex `"^A.|^B."` which looks for lines starting with either A. or B.:

```
docs_df %>% 
  filter(grepl("^A.|^B.", text))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   file       line text                                         
#>   <chr>     <int> <chr>                                        
#> 1 txt_1.txt     1 A. The First:  abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
#> 2 txt_1.txt     2 B. The Second: abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
#> 3 txt_1.txt     6 A. The First:  abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
#> 4 txt_1.txt     7 B. The Second: abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
#> 5 txt_2.txt     1 A. The First:  abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
#> 6 txt_2.txt     2 B. The Second: abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
#> 7 txt_2.txt     6 A. The First:  abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
#> 8 txt_2.txt     7 B. The Second: abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyz.
```

For export to Excel I recommend `rio::export()`.

Comment: I am still need to assign each gregexpr() extraction its own line. 

Can we reconcile yours:
docs_df <- lapply(docs_text, function(f) {
  lines <- readLines(f)
  tibble( file = basename(f), line = seq_along(lines), text = lines)}) %>% bind_rows()

Comment: With mine: docs_doc <- lapply(docs_list, function(i) {
  j <- paste0(scan(i, what = character()), collapse = " ")
  regmatches(j, gregexpr("(?<=A. The First).*?(?=C. The Third)", j, perl=TRUE)) })
lapply(1:length(docs_doc),  function(i) write.table(docs_doc[i], file=paste(docs_list[i], " ", " ", sep="."), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, eol = " " ))

Comment: Please excuse the crunched code in the previous two comments. I was trying to save space

Comment: I didn't notice you only wanted certain lines. I updated my answer.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your efforts on this, I really appreciate it! That is what I asked for, however, I'm realizing I need to clarify through adjusting my question. My current project goal is to extract text from multiple lines between "A." and "C." into one line each. And have thus updated my output request above to clarify.

Comment: Oh, I thought I was just clarifying my question. I apologize and will make sure to be more careful on my SO etiquette moving forward. I will repost the same question with the added clarification. Thank you for your time answering this question and feedback in engaging this community! Your insights helped me find clarity!

Comment: Great! Sorry if that sounded harsh. I was in a rush and it sounded a bit nicer in my head...

Comment: No problem. I really do appreciate the feedback though.